# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property

Tags: jpa, hql

Al ejecutar la consulta *calculoTotalPlazasLicitadasPorProvincia* obtengo el '*org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: VmProvincia of: es.assda.ged.persistence.model.TGenPlazasLicitadas*'

No entiendo porqué me dice que no puede resolver la propiedad cuando creo que esta mapeada correctamente.

En BD esta hecha la FK de TGenPlazasLicitadas a VmProvincia con la salvedad de que puede ser nula.

Con *@JoinColumn(name = "IDPROVIN", nullable = true)* ocurre igual

Mapeo de **TGenPlazasLicitadas**:

```
...
private VmProvincia VmProvincia;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "IDPROVIN")
public VmProvincia getVmProvincia() {
    return VmProvincia;
}

public void setVmProvincia(VmProvincia vmProvincia) {
    VmProvincia = vmProvincia;
}
...
```

Consulta **HQL**:

```
...
StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();
hql.append(" SELECT DISTINCT plalic.idplalic ");
hql.append(" FROM TGenPlazLiciOfer AS plalicofer ");
hql.append(" INNER JOIN plalicofer.TGenPlazasLicitadas AS plalic ");
hql.append(" INNER JOIN plalicofer.TGenPlazasConv AS pconv ");
hql.append(" INNER JOIN pconv.TGenConvenios AS conv ");
hql.append(" INNER JOIN plalic.TGenLicitaciones AS licitaciones ");
hql.append(" INNER JOIN plalic.VmProvincia AS provincia ");
hql.append(" WHERE plalicofer.fechbaja IS NULL ");
hql.append(" AND plalic.fechbaja IS NULL ");
hql.append(" AND pconv.fechbaja IS NULL ");
hql.append(" AND conv.fechbaja IS NULL ");
hql.append(" AND licitaciones.fechbaja IS NULL ");
hql.append(" AND provincia.fechbaja IS NULL ");
hql.append(" AND provincia.idprovin = :idprovin  ");
hql.append(" AND licitaciones.caracter in (:caracter) ");
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Java Hibernate, el nombre de la propiedad debería ser:

```
private VmProvincia vmProvincia;
```

Con la primera letra en minúscula, ya que el objeto empieza en mayúscula.

También modifica el set y cambia el actual por este:

```
public void setVmProvincia(VmProvincia vmProvincia) {
    this.vmProvincia = vmProvincia;
}
```

Aquí le dices que la propiedad de la entidad, this.propiedad, obtenga el valor del pasado por parametro.

Por otro lado, veo que las anotaciones las tienes puestas a nivel del get, lo ideal sería tenerlas a nivel de la propiedad.

[http://websystique.com/spring/spring-propertysource-value-annotations-example/#:~:text=Spring%20%40PropertySource%20annotations%20is%20mainly,specify%20the%20property%20from%20a%20](http://websystique.com/spring/spring-propertysource-value-annotations-example/#:%7E:text=Spring%20%40PropertySource%20annotations%20is%20mainly,specify%20the%20property%20from%20a%20).

Comment: Tenías razón, lo extraño es que hay otras propiedades definidas así y no dan el mismo problema. Sea como fuere, muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro que te funcione y lo puedas solucionar, de nada para eso estamos! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tuve un problema similar hace poco, al actualizar el hibernate de "5.1.14" a "5.6.8" en el proyecto que apoyo, me salía el mismo error pero se resolvió al eliminarle una línea, que en mi caso tenía en el modelo y era la siguiente:

```
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
```

Solo por eliminarlo se resolvió, no se si sea la mejor prática, pero espero sea de ayuda para alguien mas.